# Can I configure routing to a host with public ip address via a private network?

Tags: virtualization, routing, ipv4

This question has alread been posted on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/q/14904325/2012441) but since I recognized that it might be offtopic there, I'll repeat it here:

I'll explain the current situation first and then I'll describe my wishes:

## Current Situation

At the moment I have one linux machine with three public IP-Adresses configured on one physical interface. The machine can be reached via each of these IPs.

## Future

In the future I want to use virtualization on this machine and assign one of these three IPs to a specific virtual machine. But for some reasons I cannot use bridging for the physical interface and the virtual interface. Using NAT and/or PAT is also not possible.

## The Problem

My idea was to configure the virtualization host as router and set up a route for this specific public IP via the virtual network interface (with private addresses).

Is this possible at all? Did I overlook something? Or are there other solutions for my problem?

Comment: You should use bridging. If something prevents you from doing so, fix it.

Comment: The reason that prevents me from doing so is something that I cannot change - it's some configuration on the ISP side - using bridging will lead to disconnection caused by security settings.

Comment: Sounds like Hetzner.

Comment: There's a reason actual routers/firewalls exist.  This is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, AFAIR, you can do that kind of stuff with Linux networking stack, but remember — you'd need proxy arp for the external interface to be turned on (and aliased IP-address to be removed from it — more than likely, but I'm not 100 %-sure, should/could be easily verified).